# What is the difference between these 2 struct definitions?

Tags: go

What is the difference between these two struct type definitions?

```
var query1 struct {
    A, B string
}

query2 := struct {
    va1 string
    va2 int
}{"Hello", 5}
```

Why can I not initialize the first with value like second? What is the difference between them?

Comment: The first has 2 string members, the second has a string and an int. These cannot be reconciled without type-casting as far as I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "initialize the first with value like second." For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var query1 = struct {
        A, B string
    }{"Hello", "5"}

    query2 := struct {
        va1 string
        va2 int
    }{"Hello", 5}

    fmt.Println(query1, query2)
}
```

Output:

> `{Hello 5} {Hello 5}`

`query1` is a [variable declaration](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations). `query2` is a [short variable declaration](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations).